# VS Code Emmet with classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using Visual Studio Code with Classic ASP project. In Sublime Text, Emmet was working. I am having trouble trying to get Emmet working in VS Code.

Does anyone know the settings to get VS Code + Classic ASP pages working with Emmet?

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is similar to @ravi-ram above, but set:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.asp": "asp"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "asp": "html"
}
```

This way you get emmet completion for both ASP and HTML within .asp files

Answer (score 1):

According to [Emmet in VSCode - Emmet abbreviations in other file types](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types)

> To enable the Emmet abbreviation expansion in file types where it is
>   not available by default, use the `emmet.includeLanguages` setting. Make
>   sure to use language identifiers for both sides of the mapping.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>     "javascript": "javascriptreact",
>     "vue-html": "html",
>     "plaintext": "jade"
> }
> ```

Comment: Classic ASP is not an Included Language.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great extension at : https://www.itnota.com/making-visual-studio-code-colorize-classic-asp-code/

To add Classic ASP pages (*.asp) to use Emmet, you need to add the following setting changes. Settings are accessed via File > Preferences > Settings menu item. (Cntl + comma)

```
 "files.associations": {
        "*.asp": "html"
    },
```

OR

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "asp": "html"
}
```

Using *emmet.includeLanguages* did not work as Classic ASP is not a recognized Included Language.

[image]